# Internet / E-Mail Usage Policy

Tags: email, internet

Does anyone know of a resource online to check our company's Internet & E-Mail Usage Policy against, perhaps there is a standard out there that if adhered to covers everything...?

Answer (score 3):

As you're based in the UK this link may help: [Sample acceptable email use policy - Business Link](http://www.businesslink.gov.uk/bdotg/action/detail?itemId=1076142227&type=RESOURCES)

Answer (score 0):

Your policy will be influenced by a number of things, including:

- National laws
- Local laws
- Type of business

A policy that's relevant for a (say) copy shop in Germany may be irrelevant for a government contractor in the USA.